# Is there a feature to batch upload folders with files in git, svn, hg?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, cvs, dvcs

There are folders with files with names: "1", "2", "3"... and "2020070801", "2020070802", "2020070803" ... locally currently.

Is there a feature to batch upload such folders with files in git, svn, hg not step by step and in batch so to get commits with automatic creation of commit messages and history of commits?

Comment: Are you looking for one command to push files to git, svn and mercurial? Or commands for each version control software separately?

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. So you have some files in folders... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also "Upload" doesn't make any sense  in this context. You might mean to "add" files to source control?

Answer (score -1):

No, because:

1. It isn't feature of *any* SCM to replace **human brain**
2. In *any* OS and *any* shell it's a question for 2|3-liner with obvious logic ("select", "copy with overwrite", "commit")